# VideoView won't autolay... (Android/Eclipse)

Tags: android, eclipse, android-videoview, autoplay

First, I don't use an emulator because my D270 is not capable of running it, so I just send the .apk of my project to my k012 to try my app out...
My VideoView won't play my video entitled 'slideshow' which should play the moment I launched my app... Here are the properties of my video:
width: 480, height: 360, framerate: 30fps, length: 32s...
my video(slideshow) is located in my res/raw folder...
I've tried so many solutions, but it still won't work...

P.S. I'm a newbie :D and thank you

here are my codes:
activity_titlepage.xml

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.cookdroid.MainActivity"
tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:layout_width="170dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/btn_basicrecipes" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="170dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/btn_appetizers" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="170dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/btn_soups" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="170dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/btn_riceandnoodles" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="170dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/btn_fishandshellfish" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="170dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/btn_meatandpoultry" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="170dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/btn_vegetables" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="170dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/btn_desserts" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="170dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/btn_drinks" />
</LinearLayout>

<VideoView
    android:id="@+id/videocatplayer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/linearLayout1" 
    />
```

```
Recipecategories.java
package com.protosmack.thefoodofthephilippines;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.VideoView;

public class Recipecategories extends Activity {
    VideoView catplayer;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_titlepage);
        Uri videosrc=Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/raw/slideshow");
        VideoView catplayer= (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videocatplayer);
        catplayer.setVideoURI(videosrc);
        catplayer.start();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem might be because your video is not ready to play when you call catplayer.start() so try this example using setOnPreparedListener.
Also remove one of the declaration of VideoView catplayer, you have declared twice in your code.

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_titlepage);
        Uri videosrc=Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/raw/slideshow");
        VideoView catplayer= (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videocatplayer);
        catplayer.setVideoURI(videosrc);
        catplayer.requestFocus();
//try, set an setOnPreparedListener in order to know when the video file is ready for playback
catplayer.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {

            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
              catplayer.start();
            }
        });
    }
```